# node.js can't connect to mysql DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, centos

I use CentOS on my server and node.js throws error

```
CONNECTION error:  { [Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)]
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true }
```

my local version on Ubuntu doesn't throw this error and php can connect to this DB with same credentials.

I use this code to connect to DB

```
var connect_params = require('./connect');
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    connectionpool = mysql.createPool(connect_params.connection);
```

and my connect.js

```
var connection = {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'mydb'
};
exports.connection = connection;
```

Comment: Can you log from a terminal with `mysql -u root -p`?

Comment: Is your MySQL listening on the default port?  If no you could pass the port in your connection params.

Comment: @SergeiTsibulchenko did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the `portnumber` in my case worked, as I previously used `hostname:portname` (courtesy from the JDBC API) to connect with my local db.

So by specifying the `portnumber` as its own variable, instead of appending it on `hostname`, you might be able to connect to it.

Let me know if it doesn't work.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : "hostname",
port     : "portnumber",
user     : "username",
password : "password",
database : "dbname"
});
```